# Can Spree run on a multithreaded server be problematic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, postgresql, spree, puma

I have a Rails app running on Puma (3 workers, 0-16 threads each).

Lately, I have been having some issues with orders being completed with empty shopping carts, as well as orders without shipment attached, or with inexplicable multiple shipments for the same items...

I have been testing and testing for a good few days now, but I can't figure anything suspicious out from the logs, nor I am able to reproduce the issues.

So I was just wondering if there is a chance that this might be a symptom of thread-unsafe code (either my own, or Spree's, or some gem's) doing unexpected things when, e.g., multiple requests are found running on separate threads on the same Puma process.

Has anyone ever bumped into something similar? Does my assumption/theory for what might be happening even make sense?

If this might be the root cause, then would setting the Puma thread count to 1 solve it completely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick update.

I have been running Puma with 3 workers, 1 thread each, for about 1 month on my production server.

None of the previous symptoms have occurred again, so I believe that the issue is/was, in fact, due to some thread-unsafe code somewhere.

Just in case anyone stumbles into this in the future...